# Ravendb Search with OrderBy not working

Tags: ravendb

Im using the latest build of RavenDB (3.0.3800)

When I run a simple query with a Search and Orderby the Search is ignored. If I remove the OrderBy the Search works and returns the correct results

```
var query = _session.Query<Index_All.ReduceResult, Index_All>()
            .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())
            .Search(x => x.SearchTerm, "Some String")
            .OrderBy(x => x.PublishDate);
```

This just returns all results, ignoring my Search completely.

Here is my Index:

```
    public class Index_All : AbstractIndexCreationTask<MyDocuemnt,Index_All.ReduceResult>
{
    // query model
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset PublishDate { get; set; }
    }

    public Index_All()
    {

        Map = documents => from d in documents
            let customer = LoadDocument<Customer>(d.Customer.Id)
            let owner = LoadDocument<Customer>(d.Owner.Id)
            select new
            {
                SearchQuery = new object[]
                {
                    customer.Name,
                    owner.Name,
                },
                d.PublishDate,
            };


        Index(x => x.SearchTerm, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening, the only work around i have is to return the result unordered. Can anyone spot what the problem is here ?

Thanks

Comment: What query is sent to RavenDB?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want the orderby to work. The result of a [full text] Search is going to be ordered by Lucene score. That's going to give you the best matches for the search terms provided by the user. Given that, ordering by publish date would "ruin" the quality of the results.

However, I just tried this with v30k, and it appears to use the order by properly after filtering using Search.

Edit - I notice you're using "SearchTerm" for the query model and the analyze expression, but you're indexing "SearchQuery". Make those the same and it should work.